# Is it possible to test In App subscriptions for real by Distributing a App through Enterprise Distribution on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, ad-hoc-distribution, enterprise-distribution

We have an internal app which is a sample app for demonstration of In App subscription workflow integration. We have been testing scenarios in Sandbox environment and have been looking ways to be able test actual production environment scenarios with real purchases and real time periods.

We tried releasing the App on the App Store but Apple has rejected it being only a sample demonstration App. Should we be able to test the sample app with production environment scenarios using the Enterprise distribution?

Also, it would be great to know any other way around, at best being able to do it directly through XCode.

P.S: I read somewhere that how the environment is determined is based on the signing certificate used to create the build. Is there a way I can use the distribution signing certificate to sign the build while installing from XCode. Tried that by manually signing the build with distribution certificate but it doesn't install on my device.

Comment: When you have an enterprise license your app does not go through apple approval. So, in theory, you can do this test.

Comment: If this is an app that aims to the general public, the right thing to do is to use the testflight, apple test environment, to perform the tests. If the purpose is only your business, then the right is to use the enterprise license for testing and publishing.

Comment: In app purchases are not available with enterprise builds

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise apps do not support IAP since there is no associated App Store Connect account where you can define the in-app purchase.  Also, it would not make sense for an organisation to charge itself or its own employees for app functionality.

You should use TestFlight to test your app in a production-like environment, with production subscription expiration periods;

The only way to have a "full production" experience is with a released app.

Comment: Well, it might make sense. An organisation may want to provide an app where the users can purchase the same functionality at a much discounted rate than purchasing outside (like a EBooks subscription) and it may offer several additional features not relevant to the outside world. 

Test Flight doesn't provide the "Production" environment to test the app. It behaves the same as installed through XCode for IAP subscriptions. Is there a way that can be worked out?

Comment: TestFlight purchasing still occurs against the sandbox, but that shouldn't matter as your validation code should fallback to validating sandbox receipts anyway in order to pass review. Subscription periods are not accelerated with TestFlight.